# use a django built in filter in code (outside of a template)

Tags: django, filtering

I am formatting a string in python and I would like to use one of django's built in filters that is typically used in a template.  Is there an easy way to use it in lines of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the filter. In some cases you can import the module that contains the filter and access a helper function within the module, but in other cases you won't be so lucky. See the filter source for details.

Comment: thank you, the filter was actually using another django utility method that I was able to import

Answer (score 40):

Generally, yes.  For example, if your filter is in [django.template.defaultfilters](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/template/defaultfilters.py) you can run:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
slugify('what is that smell')
```

If you peruse the code though you might notice that many of these filters import code from [django.utils.text](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/utils/text.py) and [django.utils.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/utils/html.py) so you can also skip the middle-person indirection and import the function directly from those packages as they are now also [publicly documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.text).

```
from django.utils.text import slugify
slugify('progress arcs in fits and starts')
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using this in the template:

```
{{text | linebreaks}}
```

I used this to implement the linebreak filter:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import linebreaks
text = "some text \n next line"
text = linebreaks(text)
```

gives:

```
<p>some text <br /> new line</p>
```